# getAuth().onAuthStateChanged not called, async not resolving in capacitor?

Tags: ios, firebase, next.js, capacitor

This may be a firebase issue or a capacitor issue with promises - I'm building an iOS app with capacitor and NextJS.

I'm finding async functions (at least to firebase) aren't completing even when they're successful, for example a call to 'createUserWithEmailAndPassword' from firebase succeeds (the account is created on firebase) however it doesn't resolve,

onClick={() => {
console.log("begin sign up");
setLoading(true)
try {
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(getAuth(), email, password).then(data => {

```
                }).catch(e => {
                    setError(JSON.stringify(e))
                }).finally(() => setLoading(false))
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
                setLoading(false);
            }
        }}
```

This function works fine in a standard nextjs environment so the logic has been validated, making me think it might have to do with async functions in capicitor.

I also seperately have a hook into the callback: getAuth().onAuthStateChanged and getAuth().onIdTokenChanged which are never called.

Update: I used proxyman to inspect network traffic - the sign in request is suceeding with a valid payload returned however on the capacitor side it's not resolving (i.e. calling 'then' or setting a user on the firebase auth).

Comment: Do you use any Capacitor Firebase plugin?

Comment: No, as the only plugin I could find stated that it's very erays to make email sign in work which is what I'm doing - I expected it would work, and as I said it does, except  the promise funciton never seems to complete..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have the following problem: https://github.com/robingenz/capacitor-firebase-authentication/issues/78

This was the solution (Source: [harryherskowitz.com](https://harryherskowitz.com/2021/08/23/firebase-capacitor.html)):

```
function whichAuth() {
  let auth
  if (Capacitor.isNativePlatform()) {
    auth = initializeAuth(app, {
      persistence: indexedDBLocalPersistence
    })
  } else {
    auth = getAuth()
  }
  return auth
}

export const auth = whichAuth()
```

You must set `indexedDBLocalPersistence` as `persistence` when you initialize auth.